Call Matlab function in asp.net (Web Form)
I writed a function (m.file) in matlab and want to use it in ASP.Net (Web Form) project.
I do library compiler works and add dlls to references of asp.net project, but when run the project VS sended this Error:
"System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'fis1.Class1' threw an exception
BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)".
I do this steps in Windows Form Application and used dlls files and work correct, but in asp project, after run i have error and  see Exception throw.
can anyone explain what is the problem?
In library complier should add MyAppInstaller_mcr to package?

force the project to run as x32 bits, or as x64 bits (depending on the version of matlab). That error does suggest that the bit size of the project is the issue. As a result, don't use ANY CPU, but set and force the project to run as the same bit size as matlab.
